# How to write the path to a file in Python saved in a folder on Mac?

Tags: python

I have a file saved in a folder on the desktop. I want to read that file in python but I am not sure how to specify the path to my file.

Comment: Here's a tutorial to find your file path: https://macpaw.com/how-to/get-file-path-mac - To read it, just do: `with open('FILE_PATH') as f:` - You can then use `f` as your variable for your file. You can read a tutorial on file handling [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-handling-python/).

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file-path') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

Then `contents` will contain what's in the file

Read more:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp